# 1px margin on span-columns with Bourbon Neat

Tags: bourbon, neat

I want to do this:

```
@include span-columns(4 of 12, block-collapse);
```

...but I want a 1 pixel margin on the right side of column 1 and 2, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isnt really a good way to do that. However you do have a couple of options:

1. use padding
2. use border-right: 1px solid transparent;
3. copy the output css and then add 1 px to it using `calc()` and add that to the scss after the mixin

example

```
.card {
  @include span-columns(4 of 12, block-collapse);
  margin-left: calc(??% + 1px)
}
```